# Radius of convergence of a Taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I'm currently working my way through Lanczos' Linear Differential Operators, and had a question from the same.

Find the radius of convergence of the Taylor expansion of $e^{-1/x^2}$, if the center of expansion is at the point $x=4$. The answer is stated to be $R=4$.

My understanding is that this function has no singularities, on the real line or in the complex plane. Hence the radius of convergence must be infinite. Is this incorrect? What subtlety am I missing?

Comment: What do you think the function value is at x= 0?

Comment: I kept looking at $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} e^{-1/x^2}=0$, and thought the function value existed at zero. This would be my mistake, yes?

Comment: Yes, the point is that even though the limit  exists, the function itself has no value at x= 0.  This would be a "removable discontinuity"  with the discontinuity "removed" by redefining the function to be 0 at x= 0.  But then it is a different function.

Comment: Maybe this is of your interest: the function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$, together with $f(0)=0$, is the tipical example of $C^\infty$ function which it is not analytic, because $f^{n)}(0) = 0$ for every integer $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that $lim_{x \longrightarrow 0} \ e^{-1/x^{2}} = 0$ in the complex plane.

\begin{equation}
lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{i}{n} = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ e^{-1/(\frac{i}{n})^{2}} = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ e^{n^{2}} = \infty
\end{equation}

Thus, function has a singularity on $x = 0$ so $R=4$.